# Windows 8 services fail to start

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, services

I have Windows 8 64-bit and some HDDs randomly appear that do not exist. I went into the BIOS to check if they were there (they weren't there), and booted without modifying any settings. Windows froze at login, so I reboot and it freezes.

Then I tried to use my normal password instead of the PIN code, and it worked.

I rebooted and tried the pin code and the pin code froze again, so I put the machine to sleep, and logged in using my password which worked, but once I am in Windows, the audio, WiFi, and security services have not started up.

When I attempt to start them I get this message:

```
Windows could not start the WLAN AutoConfig service on Local Computer.  
Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start.
```

Basically Windows can't start the service that I need to start.

Answer (score 0):

Some recent registry changes may caused the change ,Try this out :

Click start->Type in regedit

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet / Services / Ndisuio`

On the right panel, see the "Start" entry. If that is set to 4, change it to 3.

Navigate to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet002 / Services /
>   Ndisuio

if the "Start" entry is set to 4, change it to 3.

Then check if you are able to start those services.

Additionally you can try replacing **winsock.dll** from other computer/internet and place it at system32 folder of your operating system

Comment: I don't have a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet002 / Services / Ndisuio

nor a winsock.dll but i do have a winsockhc.dll

and the value was 3 on the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet / Services / Ndisuio

Comment: have u tried to replace winsock dll of other computer?normally winsock might be a issue@Mixchew

Comment: there in no winsock.dll in my sys32 folder, but there is a winsockhc.dll

Answer (score 0):

Enter registry editor.

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
"SYSTEM"
"CurrentControlSet"
"Services"
"Dhcp"
Double click on "DependOnService" 
Delete everything in the words in text area, except "Afd", and click OK.

Get back to
"Services"
"EapHost"
2x click on "DependOnService"
Remove everything in the text area.

This should fix it.